# How to install specific version of python on Alpine linux

Tags: python, docker, alpine-linux, version, apk-tools

I am using docker's official [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker) and want to install python3.9.6

Running this installs python 3.10.x

`apk add --update --no-cache python3 && ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python`

and I can't figure out how to specify exact version of python I want to install.

Please don't suggest using docker images with python preinstalled

Answer (score 2):

You did not specify which tag you are using for the image from https://hub.docker.com/_/docker, but your question specifies Alpine so I will try to explain that.

There is usually only one packaged version of Python in any given version of Alpine.

The most recent [Alpine v3.16 has packaged Python v3.10.5](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=python3&branch=v3.16).

You can get [Python v3.9.5 by using Alpine 3.14](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=python3&branch=v3.14) or [Python v3.9.13 by using Alpine 3.15](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=python3&branch=v3.15)

I do not see that Python v3.9.6 has been packaged for any version of Alpine.

You should be able to change the tag for the image from https://hub.docker.com/_/docker to match the desired version of Alpine.

If you really need to use Python v3.9.6, your best option may be to use one of the official [Docker Python images](https://hub.docker.com/_/python) and specifying one of the `3.9.6` tags

Answer (score 1):

There are virtual environment software packages with features for installing and managing different versions of Python.  Some can even install more than one version at a time and switch between versions at will.

The two I've used for Python are `virtualenv` and `pyenv`.  They're Open Source Software (OSS) projects, but they have reasonably simple steps to install:

Virtualenv:  https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/
Pyenv:  https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Answer (score 0):

I tried many answers from different sources, eventually I copied the repository file and checked the naming convention by extracting the compressed file :

```shellsession
$ wget https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main/aarch64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
$ tar -xvf  APKINDEX.tar.gz
$ cat APKINDEX | grep python3
```

and the found the line.

```
D:python3 python3~3.11
```

and the following worked

```shell
apk --update --no-cache add python3~3.11   --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main
```